# Django /w MySql : Query data according to the foreign Key ( Filter / get / get_object_or_404( ))

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I started Django since 2 weeks and I try to obtain information of the table 'Salary' with regard to the pk ' matriculeemp ' selected in the url,'matriculeemp' is the foreign key of 'Salary' and the pk of the table employe.

I was not able to to find the answer by looking on other post of stackoverflow nor by posting mine on other forums, thus I come to you. I have these models and this view. These paths in my urls.py of my folder of application :

Models

```
class Salaire(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(db_column='Date') 
charge_patronale_mensuel = models.FloatField(db_column='Charge_Patronale_Mensuel', blank=True, null=True) 
charge_salariale_mensuel= models.FloatField(db_column='Charge_Salariale_Mensuel', blank=True, null=True) 
autre_charge_mensuel_fixe = models.FloatField(db_column='Autre_Charge_Mensuel_Fixe', blank=True, null=True) 
salaire_brut_mensuel = models.FloatField(db_column='Salaire_Brut_Mensuel', blank=True, null=True) 
matriculeemp = models.ForeignKey(Employe, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='MatriculeEmp', blank=True, null=True) 
salaire_net_mensuel = models.FloatField(db_column='Salaire_Net_Mensuel', blank=True, null=True) 
charge_variable_mensuel = models.FloatField(db_column='Charge_Variable_Mensuel', blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'salaire'
    ordering = ["date"]

class Employe(models.Model):
    matriculeemp = models.AutoField(db_column='MatriculeEmp', primary_key=True)
    nomemp = models.CharField(db_column='NomEmp', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True) 
    prenomemp = models.CharField(db_column='PrenomEmp', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True) 
    datenaissanceemp = models.DateField(db_column='DateNaissanceEmp', blank=True, null=True) 
    dateembaucheemp = models.DateField(db_column='DateEmbaucheEmp', blank=True, null=True) 
    genreemp = models.CharField(db_column='GenreEmp', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True) 
    codefonc = models.ForeignKey('Fonction', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CodeFonc', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    codecateg = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CodeCateg', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    codeville = models.ForeignKey('VilleEmp', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CodeVille', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    codedepartement = models.ForeignKey(DepartementEmp, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CodeDepartement', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    date_de_sortie = models.DateField(db_column='Date_De_Sortie', blank=True, null=True) 

def __str__(self):
    """
    String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
    """
    return self.nomemp

class Meta:
    db_table = 'employe'
    ordering = ["nomemp"]
    verbose_name = "Employé"
```

Views

```
class EmployeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Employe
    def employeDetailView(self,request,pk,salaire__matriculeemp):
        try:
            employe=Employe.objects.get(pk=pk)
            salaire=get_object_or_404(pk=matriculeemp__matriculeemp)
            #Book.objects.filter(publisher__name='BaloneyPress').count()
            #albumgroupe= Album.objects.filter(nomgroupe__nomgroupe__contains=request.POST['searchgroupe'])     

        except Employe.DoesNotExist:
            raise ("Book does not exist")
     return render(
     request,
     'Compta-IMC/employe_detail.html',
     context={'employe':employe, 'salaire':salaire}
     )
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('employes/', views.EmployeListView.as_view(), name='employes'),
#path('employe/<int:pk>', views.EmployeDetailView.as_view(), name='employe-detail'),
path('employe/<int:pk>', EmployeDetailView.as_view(), name='employe-detail'),

 ]
```

My goal is to retrieve all the information of a salary in relation to the matriculeemp pass in pk in the url, to post them in my template employee_detail.html, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What you mean by *not working*? Any error?

Comment: I don't have any error, just the salaire informations/data are not usable in my employe detail view when i'm using {{salaire.salaire_brut_mensuel}} for example.

Comment: What is your output of `salaire`?

Comment: The output of salaire will be the 'salaire' object selected by the employe id which is mastriculeemp, it's why in my render i have 'salaire':salaire , to use the selected object in my employe_detail view.
I tried that to test and explain better but this not working :
salaire =Salaire.objects.filter(matriculeemp__matriculeemp=employe.matriculeemp)
Hope this will be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are defining different method `employeDetailView` in your `DetailView`.
You can simply define `template` and use `context_object_name` in the html as follows. 
`employe.salaire_set` gives all related Salary data for that employee.

```
class EmployeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Employe
    template_name = "Compta-IMC/employe_detail.html"
    context_object_name = 'employe'


 {% for salarie in employe.salaire_set.all %}
    {{salarie.date}}
    ....
  {% endfor %}
```

For getting latest item, you can define `Meta` property in your `Model` as follows:

class Salaire(models.Model):
     ....
     ....

```
 class Meta:
     get_latest_by = 'date'
```

Now, you can get the latest item as :

```
            {{employe.salaire_set.latest.date}}
            {{employe.salaire_set.latest.charge_patronale_mensuel}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but  I'm not trying to place the template inside the view, I need to use the object returned by the context.

I first though this was accessible in the template as salaire.charge_salariale_mensuel

I need a certain modularity of the data object to make operations in the future.

Comment: I finally understood that you meant, but if i do that i have all the salarie of the database for an employe, if i wanted to have just the last salarie for an employe, how i can do ?

Comment: @BastianRobert, I have edited my answer.I have not tested it but let me know if it gives any error.

Comment: This is actually working, it don't gives any type of error, i'm thankful of your help :)

Comment: @BastianRobert. Please do approve the answer and close it. I am glad it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from the question you want to fetch the Salarie based on the employee's id
Then this should work fine to load data from Salarie table

```
class EmployeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Employe
    def employeDetailView(self,request,pk,salaire__matriculeemp):
        try:
            employe=Employe.objects.get(pk=pk)
            salaire=get_object_or_404(matriculeemp=employe)
            #Book.objects.filter(publisher__name='BaloneyPress').count()
            #albumgroupe= Album.objects.filter(nomgroupe__nomgroupe__contains=request.POST['searchgroupe'])
        except Employe.DoesNotExist:
            raise ("Book does not exist")
     return render(
     request,
     'Compta-IMC/employe_detail.html',
     context={'employe':employe, 'salaire':salaire}
     )
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant, but this code is actually not working :/